# MAX485 chips burning out easily

Tags: python, temperature

I've ordered some MAX485 chips to establish a connection between a RPi and multiple Arduino Mini's. This is working great, but the MAX485 chip on the RPi side gets quite hot. I've burned around 4 chips until now.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, as it seems to send and receive contents correctly.

Below is a picture of the MAX485 sending and receiving data with Python:
[image: PuTTY showing the MAX485 chip working]

I've hooked it up this way:

[image: Wiring MAX485]

In operation it gets around 40-45°C.

I've tested letting the transmit Pin "High", and then it gets really hot (to the touch, far more than 45°C).
After a few days, it simply doesn't work anymore. No visible sign of damage, but it receives/sends unreadable garbage.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

--

**EDIT:** Here a picture of what a "broken" chip does:
(This chip isn't that much damaged, I've burned others that I won't even recognize a single character)
[image: Broken chip receives garbage]

**EDIT 2:** When the Transmit Pin is "LOW" (0.01V):
[image: 28.4°C when the Pin is LOW]

And when the Pin is "HIGH" (3.26V), after just 5 minutes (and raising):
[image: 42.1°C when the Pin is HIGH]

**EDIT 3:** For the sake of completeness, I checked the datasheet and the voltages that I'm driving to the MAX485 Transmit Pin, are totally acceptable:
[image: MAX485 Voltages]

And the 5VDC that I'm driving the MAX485 is also acceptable:

[image: 5VDC MAX485]

**EDIT 4:** I have tested putting an 1K resistor between the Transmit Pin (RPi -> MAX485), but no success, it continues raising the temperature. When I tried a 2K, the MAX485 didn't even pull the transmit "flag", in other words, nothing was sent through (and it still got hot very quickly).

Comment: Your module appears to be running at a 5V logic level. Do you have anything between the module and the Pi to convert between 5V and the 3.3V required by the Pi's GPIO pins?

Comment: No, I hooked it up directly to the Pi.

Comment: That's likely to be a problem. The Pi's pins are only 3.3V tolerant. If you feed a 5V signal into one of them you're likely to do some damage to the Pi. I don't know for sure what happens in the other direction, but your module is likely to be happier if you feed it the 5V it's expecting rather than the 3.3V supplied from the Pi's pins. You could try using a logic level converter or voltage divider between the Pi and the module to convert appropriately.

Comment: @goobering I've measured the Pin 23 on the Pi and at the "HIGH" state, it reads 3.26V, so you're right, but... I've hooked up the Transmit Pin to 5V to see if the module is gonna to be happier, but it gets too hot in the same way. That doesn't seem to be the problem...

Comment: Did you hook a signal pin on your module straight to the Pi's 5V rail? The Pi's 5V pin is just a dumb rail, hooked directly to the 5V line on whatever power supply you're using to power the Pi with. You can't use it to transport usable signals anywhere, it's just a power line. I would test the module, per my previous comment, using a [logic level converter](https://www.adafruit.com/product/757) or [voltage divider](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/voltage-dividers) between the module and the Pi.

Comment: 40-45°C isn't enough to burn an IC out, in fact [the datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf) says it is fine to 70°C.  If there were enough heat to damage it, it should be *at least* very uncomfortable to touch for more than a few seconds.  However, incorrect TTL levels will produce errors; the problem isn't just the high, it's also the low threshold.

Comment: @goldilocks When the Pin is "LOW", the chip cool down immediately. When it's "HIGH" it gets hot, even without transmitting anything...

Comment: My point about about the low threshold was WRT to logic levels.   But again, to emphasize:  **42°C is NOT too hot.**  Not anywhere close.  I'd bet money it is *totally normal*.   Pretty much any working IC will be that warm (and the fact that it isn't transmitting anything doesn't mean it isn't "working", spinning its wheels).

Comment: Anyway, if you are dead set on pursuing that, I suggest you take it to our larger sibling site, [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).  There isn't anything here that is particularly pi specific (besides the fact you have it connected wrong).

Comment: @goldilocks Is there any option to "move" the question to that site (Since it's StackExchange too)? (And thanks for helping, too)

Comment: Yes, cut and paste from the editor (you can leave the image links and everything the same).  I won't migrate it directly because there is a good chance they will close it there too, which bounces it back and leaves you in limbo.   I would think hard about your whole premise here and perhaps ask "What is wrong with this arrangement?", indicating there's a 3.3V device on one end, rather than asserting that the problem is the chips are being burned out, because all the evidence you've presented is to the contrary.

Comment: Maybe it's just not made for staying "HIGH" for long periods of time, maybe it's because the 3.3V (Very unlikely, because I already tried 5V), maybe  "DE RE" aren't mean to be shorted (On the internet I find tons of people doing that, so I assume it's ok)... I think I'll leave how it is now, because in normal operation they don't seem to burn out that quickly.

Comment: MAX485 should not get that hot.  My guess is that your circuit is wrong or incorrectly wired. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/122425/75176b-running-very-hot

Comment: @stark My solution to bring down the temperature was to send, receive and then add a little "time.sleep(.01)". Now the temperature goes and stays into a confortable zone (29.8°C). Even with that sleep, the ping stays at 11ms, which is acceptable.

Comment: @goldilocks Let me answer the question, after that, you can close it again, if you wish. (It isn't that offtopic, because the solution is on the software side)

Comment: What value pullup resistors are you using?

Comment: @Fusseldieb Not here.  This is not a MAX__ IC site.  If the folks at E.E. think you have a point, great, in which case it belongs there.  But IMO you have become very confused.

Comment: @stark I'm not using any external resistors, only setting it up software sided with `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` and `GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)`

Comment: @goldilocks Sorry about that..